# nested fields_for form not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I'm using a nested fields_for that isn't displaying, any ideas? I think my relationships are setup correctly but the field isn't rendering at all.

MODEL EXCERPT

```
class DaysEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :location

accepts_nested_attributes_for :event
```

TRUNCATED VIEW

```
<%= form_for(DaysEvent.new, :remote => true, :html => { :class => "form-inline"} ) do       |f| %>


<fieldset>
<%= f.fields_for :event do |event_form| %>   
 <div class="control-group">
  <%= event_form.label :allow_user_to_suggest_dates, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= event_form.check_box :allow_user_to_suggest_dates, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because accepts_nested_attributes_for allows you to save attributes on associated records through the parent, whereas you are trying to save attributes through the child. Either DaysEvent needs to be made the parent of Event, or Event must accept_nested_attributes for DaysEvent, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hm really? Well neither of those two options sound like what I want. Can I just add the event field without it being in the model(daysevent) and just handle it in the controller?

Comment: The reason you're not seeing anything in fields_for is that the newly created DaysEvent (from DaysEvent.new) doesn't have an associated :event, so `f.fields_for :event` doesn't execute the block. There needs to be an existing Event form the DaysEvent in this for to "belong_to".

Comment: I think I get what you're saying and I tried creating a new days_event in the controller, attaching it to the new event and using @newevent.days_events but kept getting errors. I ended up just using a check_box_tag and update the event attributes in the controller